Android app integrate HWAddress Sanitizer run app failed
I intergrate hwaddress sanitizer according to the document: enter link description here
then run the app,  log output shows run wrap.sh failed
#!/system/bin/sh
echo "wrap Running with HWASAN $@"
LD_HWASAN=1 exec "$@"

11-14 18:17:25.908 22617 22617 I wrap.sh : wrap.sh terminated by signal 11
11-14 18:17:26.023 22769 22769 I wrap.sh : wrap Running with HWASAN /system/bin/app_process64 -Xcompiler-option --generate-mini-debug-info /system/bin --application --nice-name=com.xhey.xcamera com.android.internal.os.WrapperInit 81 33 android.app.ActivityThread seq=3055
11-14 18:17:29.401  2716  2840 D ViewRootImplExtImpl: wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=360, relayoutAsync=false, newFlags=23592960, title=Splash Screen com.xhey.xcamera
11-14 18:17:31.475 22769 22769 I wrap.sh : wrap.sh terminated by signal 11
11-14 18:17:31.582 22981 22981 I wrap.sh : wrap Running with HWASAN /system/bin/app_process64 -Xcompiler-option --generate-mini-debug-info /system/bin --application --nice-name=com.xhey.xcamera com.android.internal.os.WrapperInit 81 33 android.app.ActivityThread seq=3056
11-14 18:17:34.909  2716  2840 D ViewRootImplExtImpl: wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=360, relayoutAsync=false, newFlags=23592960, title=Splash Screen com.xhey.xcamera
11-14 18:17:36.908 22981 22981 I wrap.sh : wrap.sh terminated by signal 11
11-14 18:17:37.020 23128 23128 I wrap.sh : wrap Running with HWASAN /system/bin/app_process64 -Xcompiler-option --generate-mini-debug-info /system/bin --application --nice-name=com.xhey.xcamera com.android.internal.os.WrapperInit 81 33 android.app.ActivityThread seq=3057
11-14 18:17:40.367  2716  2840 D ViewRootImplExtImpl: wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=360, relayoutAsync=false, newFlags=23592960, title=Splash Screen com.xhey.xcamera
11-14 18:17:42.461 23128 23128 I wrap.sh : wrap.sh terminated by signal 11
11-14 18:17:42.564 23298 23298 I wrap.sh : wrap Running with HWASAN /system/bin/app_process64 -Xcompiler-option --generate-mini-debug-info /system/bin --application --nice-name=com.xhey.xcamera com.android.internal.os.WrapperInit 81 33 android.app.ActivityThread seq=3058
11-14 18:17:45.858  2716  2840 D ViewRootImplExtImpl: wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=360, relayoutAsync=false, newFlags=23592960, title=Splash Screen com.xhey.xcamera
11-14 18:17:47.890 23298 23298 I wrap.sh : wrap.sh terminated by signal 11
11-14 18:17:48.004 23467 23467 I wrap.sh : wrap Running with HWASAN /system/bin/app_process64 -Xcompiler-option --generate-mini-debug-info /system/bin --application --nice-name=com.xhey.xcamera com.android.internal.os.WrapperInit 81 33 android.app.ActivityThread seq=3059
11-14 18:17:51.348  2716  2840 D ViewRootImplExtImpl: wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=360, relayoutAsync=false, newFlags=23592960, title=Splash Screen com.xhey.xcamera
11-14 18:17:53.442 23467 23467 I wrap.sh : wrap.sh terminated by signal 11
11-14 18:17:53.556 23648 23648 I wrap.sh : wrap Running with HWASAN /system/bin/app_process64 -Xcompiler-option --generate-mini-debug-info /system/bin --application --nice-name=com.xhey.xcamera com.android.internal.os.WrapperInit 81 33 android.app.ActivityThread seq=3060

